# How to make multi rooted family member tree in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, google-visualization

I have tried with google visualization chart with database.
But problem is I can only define one relation with up line. where I can define any no of relation in down line. what I exactly want is I can link **Son's** relation with Both of **Father and Mother**  Not only with one of them.

[What Output I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9qv8.jpg)

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
            data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
            for (var i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
                var UserId = r.d[i][0].toString();
                var UnderId = r.d[i][1] != 0 ? r.d[i][1].toString() : '';
                var RelName = r.d[i][2].toString();
                var UserName = r.d[i][3].toString();
                var fName = r.d[i][4].toString();
                var ProPic = r.d[i][5] != null ? r.d[i][5].toString() : '';

                data.addRows([[{ v: UserId, f: '<b>' + RelName + '</b>' + '<br />' + '<img src="ProfilePic/' + ProPic + ' " height="80px" widht="50px"/>' + '<br />' + fName + '<br />'+'User Id :'+ UserId}, UnderId, '']]);
            }
            var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            //var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart($("#chart")[0]);
            chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

This use case comes up now and then. Google Charts' Org charts do not support multiple parent nodes. No work-around.

They have said they are planning a re-write of some of the odd-ball charts like Org Charts, to make the API a closer match to all the other charts. At this point I haven't seen any sign of a new version, and no dates announced.

Comment: thanks nbering. Is there any other way? that I can create multi parent nodes.

Comment: Use a different chart library. Like I said, no work around. One parent node is a fundamental rule to how the chart is rendered.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I have changed my html structure for this.